# How to report errors from custom QML components?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've made a MyComponent QML component with some property:

```
Q_PROPERTY(PendingList* list MEMBER list)
```

and a function:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void send();
```

It can be created in QML:

```
MyComponent {
    id: myComponent
}
```

When I call somewhere the `myComponent.send()` while the `list` property is not defined, how can I properly report the problem in the `stderr`? I'd like to see the *.qml file name and line number where `send()` was called or the line number of the `myComponent` creation.

Is there a proper way to maybe get the QML stack trace or generate `QQmlError` or throw an exception that will be handled by the QML engine?

Comment: You can `qmlEngine(this)->evaluate` a javascript snippet that trows an exception, assuming that `this` is your component deriving ultimately from `QObject`.

Comment: It's a new instance of QmlEngine? I don't think it'll show any line numbers outside that snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will have to use some private stuff.

[QTDD14 - Categorized logging in QML - Giuseppe D'Angelo](https://youtu.be/WOXI7Lhh3HU)

Git repository with the slides and the code: [qmllogging](https://github.com/dangelog/qmllogging)

### Short Version

Add to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(${Qt5Quick_PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Add some QV8Engine stuff to your `Q_INVOKABLE` function or slot:

```
#include <QtQml>

#include <private/qv4engine_p.h>
#include <private/qv8engine_p.h>

void Logger::log(const QString &message)
{
    const QV4::StackFrame frame = QV8Engine::getV4(m_engine)->currentStackFrame();

    QMessageLogger(qPrintable(frame.source),
                   frame.line,
                   qPrintable(frame.function)).warning("%s", qPrintable(message));
}
```

Geting the engine for that function:

```
QQuickView view;
m_engine = view.engine();
```

Also set the message pattern to actually show the line number (somewhere in the beginning of `main.cpp` is fine):

```
qSetMessagePattern("%{file}:%{line} - %{message}");
```